# java web start JARSigningException via remote access thought the jar is signed

Tags: jar, web, sign

I've got a problem by running Java Web Start by remote access. Although my jar is signed, I receive an exception to the console and error: "Unable to launch the application".
The exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://hostmachine/myapp.jar
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My index.html:

```
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<script src=
  "http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    // using JavaScript to get location of JNLP
    // file relative to HTML page
    var dir = location.href.substring(0,
        location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var url = dir + "myapp.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

myapp.jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://hostmachine" href="myapp.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>title</title>
    <vendor>company</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.6+" href=
       "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="myapp.jar"
        main="true" />

</resources>
<application-desc
     name="name">
 </application-desc>
 <update check="background"/>
```

My keygen.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool" -genkey -keystore myapp.keys -keypass mypass -alias jaxb-workshop.dev.java.net -validity 256
```

My jarsigner.bat:

```
C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore myapp.keys -storepass mypass myapp.jar jaxb-workshop.dev.java.net
C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin\jarsigner.exe -verify -certs -verbose -keystore myapp.keys myapp.jar jaxb-workshop.dev.java.net
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry guys for disturbing,
the restart of the server computer definitely fixed it :)